# Properly aligning div elements in a basic html/css site

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am tinkering with a basic site I plan to host my blog on in the future and I cannot manage to get one of my div elements to align with the rest of the site properly. I have linked to the project on CodePen below. I cannot seem to eliminate the white space between `.header` and `.main`. I had thought simply making the `display: inline-block` and keeping the `margin/padding/border` small would do the trick but I am obviously mistaken. Thoughts?

http://codepen.io/Kpmfastball/pen/xOvBNB

Below is the CSS for `.main`, the div class I am struggling with, and `.heading`, which is the div located right above it on the webpage.

```
.main {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 800px;
  width: 82%;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: times;
  background-color: #29BA91;
}

.heading {
  display: block;
  font-family: times;
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px;
  background-color: #0F8CB2;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: You should try Flexbox out, I'd give a link to documentation but I'm on mobile. Flexbox makes life so much easier when trying to center items, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use HTML5 tags and also why don't you use css frameworks like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) or [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites.html)?
it's a lot that you should do to make your website responsive. you're code was a little bit messy so i cleaned it up for you..

```css
h1 {
 font-size: 50px;
 text-align: left;
}

HEADER {
 display: block;
 font-family: times;
 width: auto;
 height: 150px;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 margin: 1px;
 padding:1px;
 background-color: #0F8CB2;
 color: #ffffff;
 
}

MAIN{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav {
 display: flex;
    width: 200px;
 font-family: times;
 height: 900px;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 margin: 1px;
 padding: 1px;
 background-color: #0A6D37;
 color: #ffffff;

}
.main {
 display: flex;
    flex:1;
 height: 900px;
 margin: 1px;
 padding: 1px;
 border-width: 1px;
 font-family: times;
 background-color: #29BA91;
}
.link1 {
 color: #ffffff;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>A-Not-So-Well-Respected Man Blog</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1 style="padding: 5px; border: 5px; margin: 5px">A-Not-So-Well-Respected Man</h1>
  <h5>Random Thoughts and Musings</h5>
 </header> 
  <main>
    <div class="nav">
      <h3 align="center">Menu</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Posts A-Z</li>
        <li>Posts By Tag</li>
        <li>Newest Posts</li>
        <li>About Me</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <a class="link1" href="https://anotsowellrespectedman.wordpress.com/2016/02/14/love-and-brutality-a-history-of-february-14th/">Latest blog post</a>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks so much. Yeah I am planning on working with bootstrap in the future, I just want to make sure I have the skill set to do it without frameworks just in case. Fairly new to web dev and I'm trying to absorb as much as possible!

Comment: np, if you think my answer helped you please mark it as correct answer so others can find the solution too.

Answer (score 1):

Just put this in .main:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add `float:left;` to class `nav` and class `main`, it will be like this:

```
.nav {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: times;
    width: 200px;
    height: 900px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: black;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    background-color: #0A6D37;
    color: #ffffff;
    float:left;
    }
.main {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 800px;
    width: 82%;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-width: 1px;
    font-family: times;
    background-color: #29BA91;
    float:left;

}
```